# running windows 8 and getting a .net framework error when trying to run a DVD

Tags: windows-8, .net-framework

Is it possible to reinstall .net framework if it is corrupted.  i have tried the fixes and they could not fix the issue.  I tend to need very good instructions to do any of these fixes.  here is the error I am getting:
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ProPresenter.BO.RenderingEngine.Renderer.Entities.REDVDElement.MouseDown(Point p)
   at ProPresenter.UI.Plugin.ViewModel.RVDVDPlayerViewModel.MouseDown(Point p)
   at ProPresenter.UI.Plugin.RVDVDPlayer._DisplayPanel_MouseDown(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   at ProPresenter.BO.RenderingEngine.Renderer.RVDevice._renderingControl_MouseDown(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18033 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
ProPresenter
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/ProPresenter.exe
----------------------------------------
ProPresenter.Common
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/ProPresenter.Common.DLL
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18033 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
ProPresenter.UI.Common
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/ProPresenter.UI.Common.DLL
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18033
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.dll
----------------------------------------
WindowsBase
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18033 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/WindowsBase/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/WindowsBase.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationCore
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18033 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/PresentationCore/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationCore.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18037 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18022 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 11.0.50709.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Management
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Management/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Management.dll
----------------------------------------
log4net
    Assembly Version: 1.2.10.0
    Win32 Version: 1.2.10.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/log4net.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18033 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------
ProPresenter.UI.Plugin
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/ProPresenter.UI.Plugin.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Xaml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18016 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xaml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xaml.dll
----------------------------------------
ProPresenter.BO.Session
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/ProPresenter.BO.Session.DLL
----------------------------------------
ProPresenter.BO.Common
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/ProPresenter.BO.Common.DLL
----------------------------------------
ProPresenter.BO.RenderingEngine
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/ProPresenter.BO.RenderingEngine.DLL
----------------------------------------
ProPresenter.BO.LicenseManager
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/ProPresenter.BO.LicenseManager.DLL
----------------------------------------
ProPresenter.DO.DBEngine
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/ProPresenter.DO.DBEngine.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Serialization
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18033 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Serialization/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
----------------------------------------
SMDiagnostics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/SMDiagnostics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/SMDiagnostics.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ServiceModel.Internals
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ServiceModel.Internals/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll
----------------------------------------
ProPresenter.BO.UndoRedo
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/ProPresenter.BO.UndoRedo.DLL
----------------------------------------
AxInterop.QTOControlLib
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/AxInterop.QTOControlLib.DLL
----------------------------------------
Interop.QTOControlLib
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/Interop.QTOControlLib.DLL
----------------------------------------
Interop.QTOLibrary
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/Interop.QTOLibrary.DLL
----------------------------------------
ProPresenter.DO.PCO
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/ProPresenter.DO.PCO.DLL
----------------------------------------
ProPresenter.BO.Tools
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/ProPresenter.BO.Tools.DLL
----------------------------------------
Ionic.Zip
    Assembly Version: 1.9.1.8
    Win32 Version: 1.9.1.8
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/Ionic.Zip.DLL
----------------------------------------
ProPresenter.BO.Plugin
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/ProPresenter.BO.Plugin.DLL
----------------------------------------
ProPresenter.BO.Registration
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/ProPresenter.BO.Registration.DLL
----------------------------------------
ProPresenter.UI.Registration
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/ProPresenter.UI.Registration.DLL
----------------------------------------
ProPresenter.UI.Tools
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/ProPresenter.UI.Tools.DLL
----------------------------------------
ProPresenter.UI.SlideEditor
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/ProPresenter.UI.SlideEditor.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Security
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18022 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Security/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Security.dll
----------------------------------------
ProPresenter.UI.AutoUpdate
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/ProPresenter.UI.AutoUpdate.DLL
----------------------------------------
ProPresenter.BO.Zeroconfig
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/ProPresenter.BO.Zeroconfig.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.ServiceProcess
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ServiceProcess/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.ServiceProcess.dll
----------------------------------------
ProPresenter.BO.AutoUpdate
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/ProPresenter.BO.AutoUpdate.DLL
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework.Aero2
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework.Aero2/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll
----------------------------------------
WindowsFormsIntegration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/WindowsFormsIntegration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/WindowsFormsIntegration.dll
----------------------------------------
UIAutomationTypes
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/UIAutomationTypes/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/UIAutomationTypes.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework.Aero
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework.Aero/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.Aero.dll
----------------------------------------
DvdLib
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/DvdLib.DLL
----------------------------------------
DirectShowLib-2005
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/DirectShowLib-2005.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D
    Assembly Version: 1.0.2902.0
    Win32 Version: 9.05.132.0000
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.DirectX
    Assembly Version: 1.0.2902.0
    Win32 Version: 5.04.00.2904
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/Microsoft.DirectX.DLL
----------------------------------------
CommunicationService
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/CommunicationService.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.ServiceModel
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18033 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ServiceModel/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.ServiceModel.dll
----------------------------------------
System.ServiceModel.Web
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ServiceModel.Web/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.ServiceModel.Web.dll
----------------------------------------
System.IdentityModel
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18033 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.IdentityModel/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.IdentityModel.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework-SystemXml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework-SystemXml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/PresentationFramework-SystemXml.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Expression.Encoder
    Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.0.1332.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Utilities
    Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.0.1332.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Utilities.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Types
    Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.0.1332.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Types.DLL
----------------------------------------
msvcm90
    Assembly Version: 9.0.30729.6871
    Win32 Version: 9.00.30729.6871
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/WinSxS/x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6871_none_50944e7cbcb706e5/msvcm90.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.resources
    Assembly Version: 3.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.0.1332.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/en/Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18033 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/mscorlib/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Orbifold.WPFRuler
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/Orbifold.WPFRuler.DLL
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework-SystemCore
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework-SystemCore/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/PresentationFramework-SystemCore.dll
----------------------------------------
ProPresenter.DO.Tools
    Assembly Version: 5.1.5.0
    Win32 Version: 5.1.5.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/ProPresenter.DO.Tools.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18033 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data.SQLite
    Assembly Version: 1.0.60.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.60.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/System.Data.SQLite.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework-SystemData
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework-SystemData/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/PresentationFramework-SystemData.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.GeneratedCode
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18033 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.GeneratedCode
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18033 built by: FX45RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml.Linq
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml.Linq/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.Linq.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq.dll
----------------------------------------
csExWB
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.3
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/csExWB.DLL
----------------------------------------
Interop.CSEXWBDLMANLib
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/Interop.CSEXWBDLMANLib.DLL
----------------------------------------
UIAutomationProvider
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/UIAutomationProvider/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/UIAutomationProvider.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework.Classic
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework.Classic/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.Classic.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX
    Assembly Version: 1.0.2902.0
    Win32 Version: 5.04.00.3900
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Renewed%20Vision/ProPresenter%205/Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX.DLL
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualC
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 11.00.50709.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualC/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualC.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not an issue with the .Net framework, this is a bug in your DVD player application. Contact the vendor (Renewed Vision?) and see if they have an update to the software.